# How to fix this issue "signed apk is not generating when minifyEnabled true in app gradle "

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

When I enabled `minifyEnabled true` signed apk is not generating

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

I'm getting following warning:

> Warning: there were 355 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

Comment: `is not generating` why? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Possible dup of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853959/android-how-to-generate-signed-apk-with-minifyenabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to generate signed APK with minifyEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853959/android-how-to-generate-signed-apk-with-minifyenabled)